# Improve drawing speed of images inside viewpager

Tags: android, performance, uiimageview

I'm using a viewpager to show static information to the user, this includes textviews, imageviews, etc. Now my swiping of my viewpager isn't really fluid when I include images to my viewpager. So I used the hierarchy viewer to check how much time it cost to draw my images. To draw only one image (filetype: JPG, filesize: 40kB) it took more than 50ms to actually draw it. So every time the screen is redrawn (during swiping from the user) it will take up more than 50ms to fully redraw the screen, what I suspect to be the culprit of the 'swiping lag'.

Does anybody know a way to improve the drawing speed of the images? I searched through the topics here, but couldn't find a definite answer to my problem.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: It depends on many factors. How do you draw images? How many images are these? How are they loaded? You should better share some code.

Comment: I'll just put the source of the image inside my ImageView.

Answer (score 0):

implement image loader to load image in your viewpager will increase scroll speed try [This](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)

Answer (score 0):

If all the images are stored locally then while drawing them in the layout write your code in OnDraw() method of Pager Adapter.It will not take any time.

to call onDraw() use this

Call this method in the onDraw function:
 protected void onDraw (Canvas canvas) {
          drawyourImages(canvas);
}

Every time when your UI is refreshed, the onDraw function will be called. To trigger the UI refresh. Just invalidate your custom view. For example

mCustomerView.invalidate();

OR

if your image is coming from server then use AQuery/Picasso or any image loading library to load your image in onDraw() method.before calling onDraw() you have to invalidate your view.To invalidate your view you should call 
mCustomerView.invalidate(); 
in viewpager swipe method listener.